# remove the border of month-view (react big calendar)

Tags: next.js, sass, react-big-calendar

I'm using react big calendar and i want to remove the border that wrap the calendar. and also how to change the color of saturday column and sunday column? How to make it work?

[my calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ktY.png)

```
<Calendar
style={{ height: '80vh' }}
localizer={localizer}
views={['month']}
formats={formats}
components={{
  toolbar: Toolbar,
  month: {
    header: MonthHeader,
  },
}}
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

For the border you need to modify this css class:

```
.rbc-time-view {
    border: none;
}
```